# validation error in config.yml of kibana kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kibana, config

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: kibana

```
namespace: the-project
  labels:
    app: kibana
    env: dev
data:
  # kibana.yml is mounted into the Kibana container
  # see https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/config/kibana.yml
  # Kubernetes Ingress is used to route kib.the-project.d4ldev.txn2.com
  kibana.yml: |- server.name: kib.the-project.d4ldev.txn2.com server.host: "0" elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9200
```

this is my config.yml file. when I try to  create this project, I get this error

```
error: error parsing configmap.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 13: did not find expected comment or line break
```

I can't get rid of the error even after removing the space in line 13 column 17

Answer (score 3):

The yml content can be directly put on multiple lines, formatted like a real `yaml`, take a look at the following example:

```
data:
  # kibana.yml is mounted into the Kibana container
  # see https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/config/kibana.yml
  # Kubernetes Ingress is used to route kib.the-project.d4ldev.txn2.com
  kibana.yml: |-
    server:
      name: kib.the-project.d4ldev.txn2.com
      host: "0"
    elasticsearch.url: http://elasticsearch:9200
```

This works when put in a ConfigMap, it should work even if provided to a HELM Chart (depending on how the HELM templates are written)

Comment: @ashique that's great! Also, if it completely answer your question, you can accept the answer, if you want.